# Json from URL to listview

Tags: android, json, listview, gson

I am attempting to create a very simple listview, with data from a JSON API. I'm very new to android and have come across many very different and complicated solutions that are not working for me. This is a sample of the JSON data, I want the name's to be listed and them upon clicking each name, it shows a page displaying the rest of the values.

```
{
    "results": [
    {
      "name": "Luke Skywalker",
      "height": "172",
      "mass": "77",
      "hair_color": "blond",
      "skin_color": "fair",
      "eye_color": "blue",
      "birth_year": "19BBY",
      "gender": "male",
      "image": "https://loremflickr.com/320/240?lock=1"
    },
    {
      "name": "C-3PO",
      "height": "167",
      "mass": "75",
      "hair_color": "n/a",
      "skin_color": "gold",
      "eye_color": "yellow",
      "birth_year": "112BBY",
      "gender": "n/a",
      "image": "https://loremflickr.com/320/240?lock=2"
    },
}
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        try
        {
          **//  String jsonInput = "[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\",\"four\",\"five\",\"six\",\"seven\",\"eight\",\"nine\",\"ten\"]";
            JSONObject jsonInput;
            jsonInput = new JSONObject("http://public.duethealth.com/api/project.json");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonInput);
            int length = jsonArray.length();
            List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                listContents.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
            myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.setStackTrace();
        }**


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My code is in onCreate(), when I read JSON as a string(commented out line), it seems to work.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm8zq.png)

It seems I'm not understand how to read in a JSON object from URL, then read array from that Object, then print each object from that array into my listview. I understand the logic behind it, but i'm so new to android trying to code it is giving me hell. I've seen long parsing methods and stuff but it seems the solution should be as simple as a one-liner(simply reading from url). Can anyone see where my problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no one liner code to read data from the URL. Use a library like volley or retrofit to read the data

Comment: start from here : https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html